# avconv uses only the first image in directory

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv

I am trying to generate a video from a sequence of png images. With the following command, a video is created, with the expected duration:

```
avconv -framerate 20 -i '%05d.png' -b 65536k out.mov
```

Problem: only the first frame (00000.png) is used, for the whole video. Nothing moves.

The files are there, and they are different from one another:

```
gauthier@sobel:/tmp/overlay $ ll *.png | head -3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 431982 Jun  4 15:45 00000.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 446261 Jun  4 15:45 00001.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 459096 Jun  4 15:45 00002.png
gauthier@sobel:/tmp/overlay $ ll *.png | tail -3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 470976 Jun  4 15:38 00648.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 470976 Jun  4 15:38 00649.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 470976 Jun  4 15:38 00650.png
```

I suppose there is something fishy about the file name matching pattern, but I cannot find what. I tried with `-f image2`, that did not help.

Comment: Does a recent [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: When I try to install ffmpeg, apt-get tells me not to, not available, obsolete,  no installation candidate, something something. So I picked avconv. It looks like ffmpeg is still developed, strange that apt-get doesn't have a release available.

Comment: Try a build from the link I provided. Just download, extract, then run. Navigate to the directory containing the ffmpeg binary, then run `./ffmpeg ...`. The real ffmpeg returned to Ubuntu in 15.04. The long absence was due to the maneuverings of the package maintainer who aligned himself with Libav and switched Ubuntu to this fork. It provides `avconv` and the counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" in earlier Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my. Saving as `out.mp4` instead of `out.mov` worked. The second after I posted the question.